# TypeORM entity throwing error when generating migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I have a simple entity called `Picture.ts` and is has following content

```
const { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } = require("typeorm");

@Entity()
export class Picture {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: string;

 @Column()
 name: string;

 @Column()
 path: string;

 @Column()
 is_main: boolean;
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

When try running `typeorm migration:generate` it throws error like this

```
Error during migration generation:
/src/src/entity/Picture.ts:3
@Entity()
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
at /src/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at importClassesFromDirectories (/src/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:10)
```

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [in the documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/using-cli#if-entities-files-are-in-typescript), the typeorm CLI works with javascript in nodejs. So if you want to use it to wrap the execution with the ts-node library. The documentation describes it really well.